# MVC - dropdown process ajax call on change function

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but the on change function is not hitting for some reason.  I hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

I have a view that has some bootstrap tabs,  inside one of those tabs I have a dropdown list.  What I want to happen is, when the user selects a year, it make an ajax call to controller, gets the json data and populates a table with the data.  Here is my code:

In the View:

```
    <div id="StatementsTab" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <div class="text-left dash-left-padding dash-right-col-content-billing">
                            <select class="form-control edi-blue" id="ddlStatements">
                                <option value="0">VIEW STATEMENTS</option>
                                <option value="@DateTime.Now.Year">@DateTime.Now.Year STATEMENTS</option>
                                <option value="@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year STATEMENTS</option>
                                <option value="@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year STATEMENTS</option>
                                <option value="@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).Year STATEMENTS</option>
                                <option value="@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-4).Year STATEMENTS</option>
                                <option value="@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5).Year">@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5).Year STATEMENTS</option>
                            </select>
                            <br />
                            <table id="statementtbl">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

and the jquery:

```
    $("#ddlStatements").change(function () {
        console.log("change function yes");
        var yr = $("#ddlStatements").val();
        if (yr > 0){
            $.ajax({
                //var url = '../LabOrder/DeletePatientNoteAttachment?PatientNotes=' + JSON.stringify(yr);
                url: '..Members/GetStatements',
                data: 'Year=' + yr, // Send value of the drop down change of option
                dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("success");
                    // Variable data contains the data you get from the action method
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    console.log(ex);
                }
            });
           
        }
    });
```

I am not sure why but the console log is not being hit.  Please help...

Comment: Is `$("#ddlStatements").change(function () { ... })` inside an onDomReady handler (something like `$(function(){ ... })` or `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`? If not, you're probably trying to bind the change handler before the select has been rendered.

Comment: Is the jQuery loaded on that view  or in the head of the page ? Your code should work as long as the jQuery is loaded and there is no other `ddlStatements` as this one on that page.

Comment: Tieson - Yes it is inside of a document ready function

        $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: son of a B@#$%!!!  ok it was the ready function,  I wasn't closing it correctly.  Thanks everyone!  The simplest things always trip me up :)